# Mutate first differences in a panel data with groups

Tags: r

I have this dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
  country = c("arg", "arg", "arg", "arg", "arg", "arg", "arg", "arg", "arg", "bra", "bra", "bra", "bra", "bra", "bra", "bra", "bra", "bra"),
  year = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004),
  group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
  value = c(324, 134, 334, 344, 364, 334, 634, 734, 364, 324, 1124, 56574, 3564, 3564, 334, 614, 534, 784)
)
```

```
country | year | group | value
--------|------|-------|------
arg     | 2000 | A     | 324
arg     | 2001 | A     | 134
arg     | 2002 | A     | 334
arg     | 2003 | A     | 344
arg     | 2004 | A     | 364
arg     | 2001 | B     | 334
arg     | 2002 | B     | 634
arg     | 2003 | B     | 734
arg     | 2004 | B     | 364
bra     | 2000 | A     | 324
bra     | 2001 | A     | 1124
bra     | 2002 | A     | 56574
bra     | 2003 | A     | 3564
bra     | 2004 | A     | 3564
bra     | 2001 | B     | 334
bra     | 2002 | B     | 614
bra     | 2003 | B     | 534
bra     | 2004 | B     | 784
```

What I want to do is to create a new column with first differences grouped by country, year and group. I tried this but the new column had only NAs:

```
x <- df %>% 
  group_by(country,year, group) %>% 
  mutate(fd = value - lag(value))
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `year` from the `group_by` (otherwise there is only one value per group):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  country = c("arg", "arg", "arg", "arg", "arg", "arg", "arg", "arg", "arg", "bra", "bra", "bra", "bra", "bra", "bra", "bra", "bra", "bra"),
  year = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004),
  group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
  value = c(324, 134, 334, 344, 364, 334, 634, 734, 364, 324, 1124, 56574, 3564, 3564, 334, 614, 534, 784)
)

df %>% 
  group_by(country, group) %>% 
  mutate(fd = value - lag(value))
#> # A tibble: 18 × 5
#> # Groups:   country, group [4]
#>    country  year group value     fd
#>    <chr>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 arg      2000 A       324     NA
#>  2 arg      2001 A       134   -190
#>  3 arg      2002 A       334    200
#>  4 arg      2003 A       344     10
#>  5 arg      2004 A       364     20
#>  6 arg      2001 B       334     NA
#>  7 arg      2002 B       634    300
#>  8 arg      2003 B       734    100
#>  9 arg      2004 B       364   -370
#> 10 bra      2000 A       324     NA
#> 11 bra      2001 A      1124    800
#> 12 bra      2002 A     56574  55450
#> 13 bra      2003 A      3564 -53010
#> 14 bra      2004 A      3564      0
#> 15 bra      2001 B       334     NA
#> 16 bra      2002 B       614    280
#> 17 bra      2003 B       534    -80
#> 18 bra      2004 B       784    250
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-16 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>